# Limit to how many lofs devices I can set up with lofiadm?

Tags: command-line, loop-device, illumos

In the Illumos kernel based SmartOS:

Is there a limit to how many block devices I can configure with `lofiadm`?  `/dev/lofi/2` through `/dev/lofi/10` went very fast, but `/dev/lofi/11` took a while.

I am trying to set up a lofi backed encrypted zfs pool in the GlobalZone.

Thank you in advance!